# What are the available labeled twitter datasets by topic

Tags: data-request, social-media, large-datasets, social-process

I want to know about recently available datasets for twitter topics where each tweet has its topic.

Comment: Could you please add 2 or 3 examples showing how the data could look like?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thanks for your response, I looking for a dataset that contains such thing as:
UserId, TweetId, Tweet,            Topic
001,00222,Guwahati has gained a lot of prominence in recent years due to PM Shri, Political


and so on